# How to get rid of single quotes in {0} string parameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql, ado.net

I made a service and it retrieve sql command from physical xml file.

It looks like:

```
<Sql>
        <![CDATA[ 
        SELECT 
                MAX(COMM_HIST_NO) AS COMM_HIST_NO
            ,   MAX(COMMUTER_NO) AS COMMUTER_NO
            ,   MAX(ARRIVED_AT_WORK) AS ARRIVED_AT_WORK
            ,   MAX(LEFT_WORK) AS LEFT_WORK

        FROM COMMUTE_HISTORY

        WHERE COMMUTER_NO = {0}
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, {1}, GETDATE()) = 0
    ]]>
</Sql>
```

And here's what returns sql command as a string:

```
// arParams is an Array.
string.Format(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SVC/Sql").InnerText,arParms)
```

{1} is going to be a column name and I want my {1} parameter to be written as column name, which has no single quotes.

To be specific, Mybatis in Java provides `${param}` and `#{param}` and the latter one gets rid of single quotes from the string param.

.NET must have developed this feature!

Comment: You want to use parameterized queries. If this is SQL Server, you can use named parameters like `COMMUTER_NO = @commuterNo` in your query, and use `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameter` classes to execute the query with the parameters.

Comment: The problem is probably in how arParams is constructed.  Can you show us that code?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements) of using parameterized queries in C# with SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe you can use QUOTENAME({1}) which will make this a valid column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that was a simple mistake.

It worked at the first place. If single quotes are not given around the parameter, `''` will not be there.